# How do I use the `security` command-line tool to add a keychain?

Tags: command-line, keychain, ssh

I'm doing some remote Mac administration and finding myself needing to copy a keychain to the machine and then add it to the default list of keychains.

Using VNC and the GUI, this is simple: just double-click it and Keychain Access opens, revealing that it's been added. But how do you do this via terminal over SSH, so that it can be scripted? The `security` tool doesn't seem to have an "add-keychain" command or an argument to any other command that would do this, as far as I can tell.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 12):

For some reason, the feature is hidden in the form of the `-s` argument to `list-keychains`. The other gotcha is that you need to simultaneously re-add all existing keychains. This should take care of it:

```
security list-keychains -s `security list-keychains | xargs` [path to keychain you want to add]
```

Comment: A breakdown of the command for people like me who are not familiar with Linux commands structure.  
This command appends the new keychain to the existing keychains.  
The `security` command inside the backticks prints out the existing keychains and the `xargs` command removes newlines.